# how to distinguish between window close and window refresh in angular using session-storage

Tags: angular, session-storage

Angular  - I'm trying to figure out how to distinguish between browser window closed or refersh. The window:unload event is being triggered in both options. I understand that working with session-storage may do the work. I've never worked with it - Can someone supply an example ?
See my current code:
Currently using:

```
@HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ])
unloadHandler(event) {
 //That's triggered on both refresh and close browser window
 }
```

Comment: Use  window.onhashchange, it gets triggered only when the url change.

Comment: This would not solve my problem - the url isn't changing - I refresh to the same url

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange even the navigation to a same url is triggering this event since the hash is different.

Comment: @GuyE: Facing the same issue. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use session storage. The trick here is that when the tab or window closes, the session storage is cleared.

So what you can do, is set the session storage when the page loads like this:

```
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('isVisited')) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('isVisited', true);
} else {
  alert('Visited already');
}
```

The above code will only alert when you refresh.

Comment: So - what is the event to place this code in ?  I mean- when placing it in the window:unload - the sessionStorage key is still there

Comment: When you refresh it should be. What are you trying to achieve? On unload it will be there.

Comment: I'm trying to check if there aren't any other browser windows with this session - So I can clear the session, so that when opening the next browser - it will not be authenticated

Comment: Aaaah, ok. Then you need local storage which is shared between pages. And on unload you should just delete the entry.